# Increasing Scrollbar width does not increase Hitbox of the increment and decrement buttons

Tags: css, javafx, scrollbar

Hello Stackoverflow community!
I have this scrollable combobox in my javafx desktop application that I want to be wider as the default is very narrow.

[image: default]

I increase the width by setting:

```
.scroll-bar > .increment-button, 
.scroll-bar > .decrement-button {
    -fx-padding: 10.0px;
}
```

in my css file.

While that widens the scrollbar and its buttons visually the hitboxes actually stay the same size, so if I click like this the combobox popup collapses:

[image: width increased]

I could not find anyone with a similar issue, which I find weird as this would seem like a very basic issue, unless nobody ever widens scrollbars. So its probably some super obvious little thing that I am doing wrong and everyone else is not ^^.

Comment: Do you have a live demo somewhere, for example a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Rvervuurt: This if **Java**FX i.e. desktop (potentially deployed via webbrowser). No JSFiddle for that.

Comment: Actually the hitboxes are correct: Even if you click in the corner, the buttons work (as long as you keep the button pressed) but as you release, you are rigth, it closes the pop-up. The `thumb` and the `track` seem working properly.

Comment: Have you tried to use "-fx-font-size:" instead? `.scroll-bar { -fx-font-size: 20pt; }`. Like this it seems working correctly.

Comment: @DVarga you are right, I did express that wrong. Its the whole combobox then that does not increase with the scrollbar I suppose and it thinks that I click outside of it. Updating the question, I wonder if there is anything I can do about that.

Comment: @DVarga Thank you "-fx-font-size" seems to work better. Its not perfect, it still closes in the far corners, but it did that in the default size too(the hover effect and actual combox size behind it dont seem to overlap perfectly). Atleast now 90% of the buttons area is clickable without it closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following workaround seems to work:

Adjust the size of the `arrow`s instead and use `-fx-background-insets` to adjust the arrow size:

```css
.scroll-bar .increment-arrow, 
.scroll-bar .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-pref-height: 20;
    -fx-pref-width: 20;
    -fx-background-insets: 5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works! Only at the very far side/corner is the hover effect still present but the combobox collapses, but that was like that in the default javafx implementation anyway. Seems to not be completely synced. Either way 99% of the clickable area does not collapse now so thats great :).